# Lock SQL table, then perform transaction, for inserting conditional on select value

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, innodb

I need to accomplish the following:

I need to insert two rows into the same table, and either both are inserted, or neither (atomically insert two rows).

I do this using a transaction on an InnoDB table like so:

```
$db->beginTransaction();

# Using PDO prepared statments, execute the following queries:
INSERT INTO t1 set uid=42, foo=1
INSERT INTO t1 set uid=42, foo=2

$db->commit();
```

However I also only wish to insert these rows if there is no row in the table where a column has value '42'.

So I do:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM t1 WHERE uid != ?");
$stmt->execute(array(42));
if($stmt->fetchColumn() < 0){
    # There is no row with uid=42, so
    # perform insertions here as per above.
    INSERT INTO t1 set uid=42, foo=1
    INSERT INTO t1 set uid=42, foo=2
}
```

However there is a race condition here, since a row with uid=42 could be inserted right after checking for that row, and right before inserting new rows.

How should I solve this?

Can I lock the table and then perform the InnoDB transaction inside of the table lock?

Can I do the select inside of the transaction to check for existing rows with uid=42? Is that race-condition-free?

Comment: Take a look at REPLACE INTO .. rather than INSERT. However, it will perform an update if a record already exists.

Comment: It would be interesting to see your table schema.  It sounds like what you are looking to do is enforce a unique index, without having a unique index on the field itself. Though I can see that you are trying to insert multiple rows with the same uid, which doesn't really make sense to me.  It looks like perhaps your issue could be resolved via table normalization and usage of unique index.

Comment: my idea would be to double check for 42 - before you commit and afterwards.

Comment: I'm with @Mike Brant, seems like you're attempting to enforce a *unique* database column constraint but with PHP code.

Comment: Why 42? You realize it's not *really* the answer to life, the universe, and everything, right?

Comment: @MikeBrant The two rows have the same uid because they are transactions in an accounting system that represents users funds. Both of those rows are part of the same transaction (one adds funds to one account, and the other removes funds from another account). Thus they both have the same uid to identify them as a unit. So a unique index cant be used AFAIK.

Comment: I guess to me, I would have a transaction table (the show data for the overall transaction) and a transaction detail table which references the transaction table.  So for example you could have uid in the transaction table with a unique index on that field, (perhaps even autoindex if the uid doesn't need to be a specific meaningful value). Then relate to that uid on the transaction detail table. If you tried to insert data into the transaction table for a uid that already exist the transaction would fail (which your app would need to handle), but this present the need for a lookup step.

Comment: @MikeBrant: Aren't we back to the same problem again though? You have then check if the transaction is present in the transaction table, and then if it is you can insert two rows into the detail table. All of this has to be atomic.

Comment: @Olhovsky No, in this case your transaction would consist of three queries. The first to insert the data in transaction table and two queries to set the data in the details table.  You would have to look at the success of the individual insert statements before making the commit, but you should be doing this anyway. So in essence this adds one query to your transaction.

Comment: @MikeBrant Ah, that makes sense. I will consider that option.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a semaphore type of architecture. Example, create a table called "semaphore" or whatever you want to call it. Let's say that table has only one field in it, and that field is unique, and is called "sem". Now, run "INSERT INTO semaphore SET sem = 42";

Ok, that INSERT statement is atomic, and will mean that the moment after that when somebody else tries to inset 42, they get given an error stating duplicate key.

Then, do the inserts in the original table. Do all this inside a transaction. In SQL it would look like this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO semaphore SET sem = 42;
INSERT INTO t1 set uid=42, foo=1;
INSERT INTO t1 set uid=42, foo=2;
COMMIT;
DELETE FROM semaphore WHERE sem = 42;
```

The reason you do the delete afterward is two fold:

1. I guess you don't need to delete it, but let's go for clean data shall we ;)
2. The reason you delete after the COMMIT is you want to keep the blocking-lock on it until the transaction is complete.

Side-note: Semaphores are usually used when an auto-increment field won't do. Then you use a semaphore table with only one record in it to serialize inserts and block the primary key.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm willing to do this, although you would think that SQL/InnoDB has a feature that takes care of this without requiring a new table for a semaphore.

Comment: Definitely a viable solution if you need to keep all your transaction data in a single table.

Comment: Instead of semaphore table, you can use application-level locks - see [GET_LOCK](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock)